# Use user input in API calls and then use the response in a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, future, setstate

I am trying to make an app in flutter where the user enters something in a search (im using SearchDelegate). Then the app takes what they entered and makes an api request to my api with it. And then in buildResults (of SearchDelegate) it makes a Container with a Card inside that has the some data of what was returned.

```
// In _MyHomePageState
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    newsData = [_getNews("United States of America")];
  }
Future<void> _getNews(String country) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "http://localhost:3535/news?len=10&searchTerm=$country&time=3d"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        newsData = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
            .map((e) => News.fromJson(e))
            .toList();
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to load");
    }
  }
```

Right below the imports I declared the newsData variable so that its global and can be accessed in `_MyHomePageState` and in the SearchDelegate.

```
// Inside SearchDelegate extension
@override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    _MyHomePageState()._getNews(res); // res is the country they selected
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        child: Card(
            color: Colors.grey,
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            child: Center(
              child: Text("$res: ${newsData.toString()}"), // on the page this shows "Italy: [Instance of Future<void>]" Italy is an example country
            )));
  }
```

When I search in the app in the console I get an "XMLHttpRequest error", and on the app I see "Italy: [Instance of Future<void>]" with Italy being what I searched for. My API returns a list of json objects which I serialize into a list of News objects(News is my own class). Some other things I have tried include changing `child: Text("$res: ${newsData.toString()}")` to `child: Text("$res: ${newsData[0].getTitle()}")` to match the type of what NewsData should be, but this also gives me errors.

I searched Tuvalu expecting News and instead got this.
[image: Result of Searching Tuvalu]
It is not because there is not enough news on this I have tries searching other countries that have been prominent in the news as well and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use conditional statement to show default data until api response data are not fetched.

```
@override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    _MyHomePageState()._getNews(res); // res is the country they selected
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        child: Card(
            color: Colors.grey,
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            child: Center(
              child: newsData != null && newsData is List ? Text("$res: ${newsData[0].getTitle()}") : Text("loading..."),
            ),
         ),
     );
  }
```